# Generate random string Hive

Tags: string, hive

I would like to know if there is some prebuilt function to generate a random string of a certain length 3 in hive.
Something similar to what the function rand() does.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `UUID`, something like this:

```
hive> select substr(java_method("java.util.UUID", "randomUUID"),1,3);
OK
b6f
```

UUID looks like `4dca1041-9682-4eb0-9be7-bbd6c68de800`. Hyphens can be removed easily and the rest used to get substring of length required. The UUID is generated using a cryptographically strong pseudo random number generator.

Comment: Hi, java_method seems not to be working on Hive Cloudera. I get this message: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException UDF java_method is not allowed

Comment: @DroppingOff  try reflect("java.util.UUID", "randomUUID"). reflect UDF does the same. It may not work in Impala, but should work in Hive

Comment: @DroppingOff Read please also this: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/25828/udf-reflect-is-not-allowed-beeline.html

Comment: Hi, yes, indeed there are security reasons. I am not the admin of the database so I don't have the power to change that myself.

Comment: @DroppingOff In hive 2.3.0 it is added uuid() UDF. See this: https://issues-test.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12721